# Add Multiple Draggable Images to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, draggable

The following code works and creates a Draggable Image (DI).  Ive created 2 instances of type DI, test and test1.  Either one works but I can't figure out how to include both in a JFrame at the same time.  When I try to add both, I'll only get the last one added.

I've done quite a bit of reading here and I know I need to create a Jpanel and add each image to the Jpanel then to the JFrame, but in this case a DI is a JPanel.

I'm hoping someone here can help, I've been through lots of trial and error and lots of internet searching but I'm not getting closer to an answer.

Here's the code -->

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DI extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage image;
    Rectangle r;

    public DI(BufferedImage image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        r = new Rectangle(10, 10, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2.drawImage(image, r.x, r.y, this);

        //Add a border, red if picture currently has focus
        if (isFocusOwner()) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        g2.draw(r);
    }

    public void setRect(int x, int y) {
        r.x = x;
        r.y = y;
        repaint();
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        r.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("happy.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        DI test = new DI(image);
        DragHandler handler = new DragHandler(test);
        test.addMouseListener(handler);
        test.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

        File file2 = new File("sad.png");
        BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(file2);
        DI test2 = new DI(image2);
        DragHandler handler2 = new DragHandler(test2);
        test2.addMouseListener(handler2);
        test2.addMouseMotionListener(handler2);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("This is a Draggable Icon");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(test);
        f.setContentPane(test2);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DragHandler extends MouseInputAdapter {
    DI di;
    Point offset;
    boolean dragging;

    public DragHandler(DI di) {
        this.di = di;
        offset = new Point();
        dragging = false;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        if(di.r.contains(p)) {
            offset.x = p.x - di.r.x;
            offset.y = p.y - di.r.y;
            dragging = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        dragging = false;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(dragging) {
            int x = e.getX() - offset.x;
            int y = e.getY() - offset.y;
            di.setRect(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DI` should probably handle multiple images

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `setContentPane` method, the entire frame is filled with the container you provide. When you do it twice, the first panel (`test`) is replaced by the second (`test2`).

```
f.setContentPane(test);
f.setContentPane(test2);
```

When you use the existing content pane and specify a layout manager, you can make both panels visible at the same time. You can set sizes and even background colors for the panels (these background colors can be useful to see which area the panel covers):

```
f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
f.getContentPane().add(test);
f.getContentPane().add(test2);
test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 160));
test2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 160));
test.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
test2.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic concept is wrong. You are attempting to create a large component and then paint an image somewhere inside the bounds of the component. The problem is that you can't stack multiple components on top of one another.

Instead you just want to have a simple panel and you add components to this panel. Then you move the component by using the setLocation() method. So there is no need for custom painting. All the dragging code does is change the location of the components. When you do this the panel needs to use a "null layout" so are also responsible for setting the size of the component you add to the panel.

To display an image you should just use a JLabel with an ImageIcon and add the image to a panel.

The basic structure of the code would be:

```
JLabel image1 = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
image1.setSize( image1.getPreferredSize() );
image1.addMouseListener(...);
image1.addMouseMotionListener(...);

JPanel dragPanel = new JPanel();
dragPanel.setLayout(null);
dragPanel.add( image1 );

frame.add(dragPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```